# Auto digitizing features on map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, digitizing, digital-image-processing

I'm new to digitization. I have the following map and I'm trying to digitize the purple features. Is there any way to automatically digitize all the purple lines on the map.

[image]

Comment: I'll assume that you are using ArcGIS for Desktop rather than asking what GIS software you are using and waiting for an answer, or needing to close your question as too broad.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **ArcScan** extension of ArcGIS for this. This is pretty much easy for auto digitizing such simple map with **ArcScan** For more information you can check 
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/arcscan/arcscan-tutorial-interactive-vectorization.htm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those lines are not polygon boundaries, and that you are using ArcGIS for Desktop, I would try to use the [Raster to Polyline](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polyline.htm) tool which:

> Converts a raster dataset to polyline features.

If they are polygon boundaries then try the [Raster to Polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-polygon.htm) tool instead:

> Converts a raster dataset to polygon features.